# React - Document title add icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement the same thing as shown on my picture below with React 18.
[image: Document title example]

Does anyone know how to add an animated red circle on my browser tab dynamically with React?

Thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not something you can add by modifying `document.title`, it is managed by the [Media Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API)